# HashMap Java example to avoid collision

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using `HashMap` in java to store key and `Object <Key,Object>`.  And I read about hashmap collision and I am trying to avoid it by using linked list.

I did some search online, but I couldn't find an example how to do this.

Can somebody point me to an online resources that implement the hashmap with linked list?

Comment: override hashcode() & equals() with THE BEST hashing algorithm? Aren't we doing too much analysis (unless you are writing scientific application).

Comment: Well, if you're worried about using HashMap because of collisions, don't be. It takes care of everything for you.

Comment: HashMap uses a linked list already. It also permutes your hashCode so it does matter so much if its not very good.

Answer (score 8):

The Java HashMap already handles collisions for you in this way. All you need to do is ensure you are overriding and implementing the key's `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.

Each `hash code` will map to a specific "bucket". Each bucket contains a linked list for the case of collisions.

The only way to avoid (or rather *minimize*) collisions is to create a hash function that creates the best possible distribution of values throughout the HashMap. Depending on the density of your HashMap and the quality of your `hash code`, collisions are almost inevitable, hence the need to override the two methods.

**Edit**: The OP asked for an example

To override the two methods:

```
public class MyObject {
  String var1;
  int var2;

  //...
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null) return false;
    if(this == obj) return true;      // Reference equality
    if(!(obj instanceof MyObject)) return false;
    MyObject myObj = MyObject(obj);
    return (var1.equals(myObj.var1)) && (var2 == myObj.var2); 
  }
  public int hashCode {
     return var1.hashCode() ^ var2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My next question is how to override those two method and what I am really overriding to?

Comment: @Tony: I have updated my response with a very general example.

Answer (score 5):

The collision only occurs if you use the same `object` as key, or different `object` as keys with the same [hash code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

For using correctly a HashMap, you should implement correctly in your key class the hashCode and equals method. Read the Object docs and [this article](https://www.journaldev.com/21095/java-equals-hashcode).

If you want to store more than one object by key, you should create a HashMap of list.

This is a simple example:

```
HashMap<Object, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<Object, List<Object>>();
map.put(key, new LinkedList<Object>);
map.get(key).add(object);
```

Comment: *"The collision only occurs if you use the same key."* not really, it occurs when 2 different objects have the same hascode.

Comment: You are correct, but I gave the simplest answer because the question was cleary made by a begginer

Comment: This is called a Multimap.  One can use the Multimap implementation from Google's Guava framework to perform the same functionality and not hace to reinvent the wheel.