# Fastest way to calculate hash for Integer array without collision

Tags: java, arrays, integer, hashcode

The Java methods, Arrays.hashCode() or Objects.hash() return same hash for some Integer arrays with different content such as

```
Integer[] a = {0,4,5,0}     // hash 927520
Integer[] b = {0,3,36,0}    // hash 927520
```

Same result is returned by the custom hashcode method such as:

```
public int hash(final Integer[] indexes) {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    for (Integer i : indexes) {
        result = prime * result + ((i == null) ? 0 : i.hashCode());
    }
    return result;
}
```

I agree that this is the expected behavior. But, I want to generate distinct hashcode for them as contents are different.

What is the fastest way to calculate hash for **Integer array without collision**

Comment: Not possible. Since the hashcode is an integer only an integer array with length 1 can have hashcodes with no collision. As soon as you have more than 1 Integer in your array the number of possible values of that array is larger than the number of possible hashcodes.

Comment: It is impossible to guarantee that arrays with different content will always have a different hash code, simply because there are more possible integer arrays than there are possible hash codes. See: [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). There is no way to avoid collisions 100%.

Comment: What makes you think that you want to avoid collisions? Hash collisions are usually considered completely normal. You will be able to avoid relatively many (certainly not all) of the collisions by using a prime number that is larger than the numbers expected to be in the array. For example, if your numbers go up to about 36, pick 127, for example.

Comment: Related? [HashMap Java example to avoid collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727811/hashmap-java-example-to-avoid-collision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bit different. First think of *why* you need `hashCode` to begin with = for fast(er) look-ups. Having two objects that would generate the same hash is not a problem at all, since that does not yet mean they are the same, of course (you would still check against `equals`).

You have  already a few comments under your question, saying that this is impossible, I just want to add some interesting things that you have not thought about (may be you simply don't know them).

In general, `hash collisions` are much more frequent in java data structures that you might imagine. According to the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and taking into consideration that a `hash` is actually `32 bits`, we get to the fact that it would take **only 77,164** unique values before there is a `50%` chances to generate a collision (and that is in the best case). So collisions are more than fine. That being said, there is [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8201462) to improve this (in my understanding by first making the hash - a `long` and working off that; but have not deep dived into it much).

Now that you know that hash collisions are more that fine, think of why they are used. Basically for fast(er) look-up. When there are two entries that have the same `hash`, it means they will end in the same "bucket" and in java, that bucket, is a *perfectly balanced red-black tree* (for `HashMap` and thus, `HashSet`) - that is still super fast when looking for entries. Thus, *in general*, any hash based structure has a search time that is *constant* (i.e.: amortized `O(1)`), so worry not about hash collisions.

Comment: Good point. Let me add: A default `HashMap` or `HashSet` has 16 buckets and will still have 16 buckets after 12 elements are added. At this point, even with a perfectly distributing hash function you have 99.7 % probability of at least one collision.

Comment: @OleV.V. well yes, that is because of the way HashMap works internally, it uses only 4 last bits to choose the bucket under those conditions...

Comment: See also [Unique hashCodes is Not Enough to Avoid Collisions](https://dzone.com/articles/unique-hashcodes-not-enough) @Maithilish

Comment: @OleV.V. dont get me wrong, but Ive written answers that are better on the subject :) with all proper respect to Peter. Its also a very old article, things have changed quite a bit

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to satisfy your requirements.

You have to understand that hashing functions can **not** create a bidirectional mapping. And that is what you would need here!

Meaning: there is a (close to) infinite number of arrays with arbitrary int values. If each of the hashes should uniquely point to a specific array setup, you could identify each array by its hash. But the range of int (or long) is not indefinite. There are simply more possible array combinations than int values to *count* them!

You can't map an indefinite set onto a set that is not indefinite.

In other words: if such a hashing method would exist, you could turn it into a compression algorithm that would reduce any content to a single int value.

So: collisions are an inherent property of hashing algorithms. You can't avoid them. If at all, you can fine tune a specific hashing function to minimize the collisions for a specific set of input data. But as said: what you are asking for is impossible from a conceptual/mathematical point of view.